# Anaconda in Windows with Power BI

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, powerbi

I am trying to work with Python in my Windows 10 Machine.  My Anaconda environment can be set by executing the following command:

```
c:\Users\bharat.c.rupare.> call c:\Users\bharat.c.ruparel\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
```

this sets up the conda environment and then I am good to go.  However, I am trying to run Python code using numpy and pandas which are pre-installed in the Anaconda stack within Power BI.  When I do that, Power BI complains that it cannot find numpy.  I understand why; because the conda environment has not been activated from within Power BI.

What do I need to do to activate the conda environment so that Power BI can find the python packages such as numpy, pandas?

Comment: You might not have provided enough info - what is in activate.bat?

Comment: It is a Windows 'batch' file that is generated by Anaconda to set its environment that also sets the path for that session of the command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using PowerBI 2.70 and it seems to not support python 3.7. Reference: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Error-when-connecting-python-to-PBI/m-p/593716

So I had to create new environment specifying python 3.6 and install the necessary packages.

```
conda create --name std_env python=3.6
```

Then in PowerBI Options, point Python home directory to your environment folder for eg. "C:\Users\a12345\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\env_py36"

Finally, import file in the python script. I'm using a pickled file but your pandas.read_csv() will also work.

```
import dill
df = dill.load(open('Z:\\folder\\file.pkd', 'rb'))
```

Comment: Some additional info about inserting the python path in power bi options: You can find the power bi options here: File > Options and Preferences > Options. Go to "Python Scripting", at "Detected Python home directories" choose "Other" and insert the path to your Anaconda environment. You can get the path by opening Anaconda Prompt, change to your environment ("activate <env-name>") and then typing "where python" (for windows).

Comment: Yes this is what I did, works well with Desktop. However, I get the same error when I schedule refresh. For some reason, my Gateway is not loading the stack from the env I created and I have no way of editing that. Has anyone had experience with scheduling refresh?

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to find the link, but Power BI doesn't play nice with Anaconda.  I installed WinPython (https://winpython.github.io) instead, and have had no problems with Power BI and python since.

Answer (score 3):

As the initial questioner assumed the problem here is the **missing activation of the conda environment**. This can be done by running the activation script like

```
Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat py37
```

where py37 is a Python 3.7 environment. This adds the following folders to the PATH:

```
Anaconda3\envs\py37  
Anaconda3\envs\py37\Library\mingw-w64\bin  
Anaconda3\envs\py37\Library\usr\bin  
Anaconda3\envs\py37\Library\bin  
Anaconda3\envs\py37\Scripts  
Anaconda3\envs\py37\bin
```

Anaconda3\envs\py37 is the Python home directory that needs to be added to the PBIDesktop global options in the *Python scripting* section too. Now all that's left is to **start PBIDesktop from within the activated environment** like:

```
(py37) C:\> "Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe"
```

If you are not using virtual environments as recommended, at least the base environment needs to be activated.

With the PBIDesktop November 2019 release I see no issues running Python 3.7 from Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use menu in Power BI Desktop to navigate to **File / Options and settings / Options / GLOBAL / Python scripting** and then set the required **Python home directory**.

You haven't provided enough info to understand which directory to choose, as your activate.bat script could contain anything.  But a likely guess would be the path to your activate.bat, removing the Scripts sub-folder.  The folder you choose should contain the file: **python.exe**.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe Mike Honey is correct and it has something to do with that .bat file, you could also try importing the modules in the code.

if you have an old version of pip you can simply do this:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'numpy'])
pip.main(['install', 'pandas'])

import numpy as np
....
```

if you have a newer version(after 10.0) of pip(import pip and run `pip.__version__`), you will need to use subprocess;

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy'])
subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pandas'])

import numpy as np
....
```